# Using environment variables in AppDynamics Python Agent configuration

Tags: python, appdynamics

What is the meaning and use of environment variables in the Python Agent configuration for App Dynamics, as documented here:

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Python+Agent+Settings

More specifically:

- If a value is set in the file and the corresponding environment variable is also set, which one takes precedence?
- If I want to use environment variables for some of these values, can they be omitted from the file?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use environment variables to configure the python appdynamics agent as well.

```
pip install appdynamics
```

Open up your repl

```
from appdynamics import config
help(config)
```

For the usual configuration values (APP_NAME, TIER_NAME, NODE_NAME, etc) you can configure them via the environment variables.  You just need to prefix them with 'APPD_'.  For for APP_NAME it would be:

```
export APPD_APP_NAME=MY_SUPER_COOL_APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the python agent in your code like so:

```
from appdynamics.agent import api as appd

appd.init(environ={'APPD_APP_NAME': 'appname',
                   'APPD_TIER_NAME': 'yourtier',
                   'APPD_NODE_NAME': 'yournode'})
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the location of your appdynamics.cfg file. That is to say, setting environment variables is not enough.

Then you need to manually start the proxy (after you `appd.init`) by running
`pyagent proxy start`

The agent configuration from your code will be automatically used by the proxy.

For a full list of config keys see the [setting docs](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Python+Agent+Settings)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to define just environment variables without changing application code. Note that variable name for controller host is APPD_CONTROLLER_HOST. You can also pass command line parameters to the process.